# How does orElseGet work in case of an Optional<List<Entity>>

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have an Optional of List of a class, i.e.: `Optional<List<MyEntity>> opListEntity`

I needed to map all `MyEntity` to `MyEntityDto` when Optional is present. In case Optional is empty, I'll return an empty *ArrayList*.

Approach 1 (Non-Functional):

Note: `myEntityMapper` is an object of a mapper class, which maps `MyEntity` to `MyEntityDto`.

```java
List<MyEntityDto> res;
if (opListEntity.isPresent()) {
       res = opListEntity.get().stream()
            .map(myEntityMapper::entityToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
       res = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This approach is fine but *IntelliJ* suggests to convert it to a functional-style expression. I let IntelliJ do the conversion and this is what I get:

Approach 2 (function expression):

```java
List<MyEntityDto> res = opListEntity.map(myEntities -> myEntities.stream()
            .map(myEntityMapper::entityToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
     .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

What I don't understand is, In approach 2 @ line 1, why is there a map?

Let me explain a bit more. See the 3rd Approach:

Approach 3:

```java
List<CustomerAddressEntity> myEntities = opListEntity
        .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
List<MyEntityDto> res = myEntities.stream()
        .map(myEntityMapper::entityToDto)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Approach 3 works fine, but if I try to convert approach 3 to approach 4, It doesn't work.

Approach 4:

```java
List<MyEntityDto> res = opListEntity.stream()
            .map(myEntityMapper::entityToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
     .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

why **approach 4** doesn't work but **approach 2** does?

what is the extra *map* doing in **approach 2** @ line 1?

Comment: Because you need to double unwrap items, the list from the optional and the items from the list. i.e. in 4 you need `flatMap`.

Comment: There is no good reason to wrap a List in an Optional. If there are no items for the List, just let it be an empty List.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes, you are right, but that code is written by someone else and I cannot modify that.

Comment: "*What I don't understand is, In approach 2 @ line 1, why is there a map?*" how else do you expect to interact with the Optional?

Comment: @VLAZ sorry, I was confused with Optional map() & Stream map(). I had not used map with optional before and I was mistaking it for Stream map(). That's why this naïve question. But things got cleared up after reading the answer below.

Comment: About 80% to 90% of the times `Optional` exists so you can call `.map()` on it. The `optionalData.isPresent()` is just garbage way to write `data == null`. The bog standard workflow is to have an Optional, `map` it, then finish with `orElse()` or `orElseGet()` to extract the plain value. `ifPresent()` is *sometimes* needed and I've not found use for `orElseThrow()` yet.

Comment: I use `orElseThrow()` sometimes when the value we require from optional is critical for the functionality to work.

e.g.: if a user send me a *profileId* that they want to see and if the user doesn't have permission to view other person's profile, despite that if they send the *profileId* of another user. I would get `Optional.empty()` from JPA, and in that case I would use `orElseThrow(<MyCustomException>)`. which would then be caught by my `ControllerAdvice` and an appropriate message would be sent back to the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it becomes obvious if you indent the code a bit more to make it somewhat easier to spot:

```
List<MyEntityDto> res = opListEntity // Optional<List<MyEntity>>
    .map(
        myEntities -> myEntities.stream() // Stream<MyEntity>
            .map(myEntityMapper::entityToDto)  // Stream<MyEntityDto>
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // List<MyEntityDto>
        )
    .orElseGet(ArrayList::new); // List<MyEntityDto>
```

That is the `Optional` (if present) is mapped to the result of transforming the contained list to a stream, mapping the elements and building a collection, or (if empty) to a new empty list.

In your 4th approach `opListEntity` is of type `Optional<List<MyEntity>>`. Now it depends on the JDK version you're using. In JDK8 `Optional` has no `stream()` method.

```
List<MyEntityDto> res = opListEntity.stream() // there is no such method in JDK8
    ...
```

Since JDK9 there is a `stream()` method but it will of course return `Stream<List<MyEntity>>` as this is the type of the `Optional`. But for the mapping to work you'd need `Stream<MyEntity>`. To get this you could map the returned stream using the [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) method:

```
List<MyEntityDto> res = opListEntity.stream() // Stream<List<MyEntity>>
    .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<MyEntity>
    .map(myEntityMapper::entityToDto)
...
```